# Как передать имя таблицы в динамический SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь передать имя таблицы как параметр связывания в в динамический SQL запрос.

Такой запрос работает:

```
DECLARE 
    FUNCTION foo (pat VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
        tabname VARCHAR2 (100) := 'mytab1';
        n NUMBER := -1;
        sqlcmd VARCHAR2 (100) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||tabname||' WHERE name LIKE :1';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcmd INTO n USING pat;
        RETURN n;
    END foo;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (foo ('bla%'));
END;
/
```

Но если попробовать задать `tabname` параметром связывания, также как с `pat`:

```
DECLARE 
    FUNCTION foo (pat VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
        tabname VARCHAR2 (100) := 'mytab1';
        n NUMBER := -1;
        sqlcmd VARCHAR2 (100) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM :1 WHERE name LIKE :2';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcmd INTO n USING tabname, pat;
        RETURN n;
    END foo;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (foo ('bla%'));
END;
/
```

, то получим ошибку:

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

Как можно задать имя таблицы параметром связывания?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL: How to pass a tablename to a dynamic SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62657796) от участника [@chris01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307297/chris01)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62657796

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Переменные (или параметры) связывания нельзя применять для идентефикаторов БД: таблиц, колонок, функций и др. обьектов БД. Или другими словами, для всего того, что не имеет конкретный тип данных.

То есть, первый запрос в вопросе один из путей задать имя идентефикатора, таблицы в данном случае, в динамическом запросе.

---

Если с переменной связывания во втором запросе была попытка предотвратить SQL инъекцию, то можно воспользоваться [`DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-44F80A6B-99B4-4DB7-8BF8-B17994AD197A). Например, чтобы избежать такой простой инъекции:

```
create table mytab1 as 
    select 1 id, 'blabla' name from dual
/
create table notmetab as 
    select 1 rid, 'xxxxxxxx' from dual;
/
create or replace function foo (tabname varchar2, pat varchar2) return sys_refcursor is
    ret sys_refcursor;
    sqlcmd varchar2 (100) := 'select * from '||tabname||' where name like :1';
begin
    open ret for sqlcmd using pat;
    return ret;
end foo;
/

var rc refcursor
exec :rc := foo ('mytab1, notmetab', 'bla%');

        ID NAME          RID   MEMO            
---------- -------- ---------- ----------------
         1 blabla            1 xxxxxxxx
```

Надо запрос в функции заменить на такой:

```
sqlcmd varchar2 (100) := 
    'select * from '||sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name (tabname)||' where name like :1';
```

Теперь инъекция завершится ошибкой, или запрос выполнится, если таблица задана верно:

```
exec :rc := foo ('mytab1, notmetab', 'bla%');
Error report -
ORA-44002: invalid object name

exec :rc := foo ('mytab1', 'bla%');

        ID NAME    
---------- --------
         1 blabla
```

Comment: Спасибо за информацию о « DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME»